# AWS RDS. Upgrade MySQL from 5.5 to 5.6, external replica and Access denied

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-replication, amazon-rds, rds

I want to create external read replica for my RDS instance using this doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html

My old instance is running mysql 5.5.27. So i started from upgrade.
I tried two ways: upgrade from read replica (create replica, upgrade, promote) and upgrade from snapshot (create, upgrade). Upgrade was successful in both ways.

```
After that i tried create user for replica access (via doc). And got access error.
mysql> CREATE USER 'repl'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'repl'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

After than i tried to create new clean instance wit mysql 5.6 and create new user. Just for test. It works like a charm!

So, where can be problem? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html) in your imported instance. This command should upgrade your grant tables.

Take a look to

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html